# Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Tags: ios, node.js, facebook, react-native, xcode7

I keep getting this error ":CFBundleIdentifier , Does Not Exist". The versions I use : react-native-cli: 2.0.1 react-native: 0.40.0 npm 4.0.5 node v7.4.0 Mac OS 10.10.5 Xcode 7.2.1 WebStorm 2016.3.2

So I proceeded with different solutions:

killing all the processes using port 8081 and resetting the port number
verifying that this Bundle already exist in my info.plist
changing the debug mode
Using this solution mentioned in this issue
But none of this solutions worked for me .So, I changed my project in the same way as Xcode suggested me to (I know it's not the perfect solution for me and ) and attached is a picture explaining it more.

I know that this is a temporary solution and I'm afraid that it will cause me some problems in the future , as I'm still a beginner and it's my first time using react-native to create iOS apps. So, does anyone have any idea or possible solution .. Thanks Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Custom compiler flags (Other C/C++/Warning flags) in Targets -> RCTWebSocket in your navigator.

This one helps me - [link](https://medium.com/@alberto.schiabel/react-native-on-xcode-beta-8-0-how-to-fix-initial-build-error-f0225c649850#.3xt6q6c8q)